# How do you prepend an IV to the ciphertext in Go?

Tags: go, des

I would really appreciate the help. I have the following [code](https://play.golang.org/p/gIee9raIQV) running. Unfortunately, I do not understand how to properly prepend the IV to the ciphertext. Line 1 is the plaintext. Line 2 is the encrypted plaintext in terms of DES (which is wrong). Line 3 is the decryption of Line 2.

`**output** 
1  Yolandi Visser
2  AAAAAAAAAAAfiIMmXF4ZPYOcypF5JA== 
3  Yolandi Visser`

Comment: please show an example of what you're trying to do. Using aes and des in the Go cipher package looks nearly identical.

Comment: Also, how do you have an IV of 32 bytes, when a DES block is only 8 bytes?

Comment: @JimB The following [code](https://play.golang.org/p/0etXPnCaye) executes, but this is not how I want to implement DES. I am facing two issues. First, the     **key**     variable throws an error when it is larger than 8 bytes. I would like to be able to specify a     **key**    in the following format: "2ybc, 2ybc, 2ybc, 2ybc, 2ybc, 2ybc, 2ybc, 2ybc". Second, the     **iv**     variable throws an error because     **iv**    length must equal block size. I would like to be able to specify     **iv**   in the same format as the key:  "2ybc, 2ybc, 2ybc, 2ybc, 2ybc, 2ybc, 2ybc, 2ybc"

Comment: You can't change the key an iv sizes, those are specified by the cipher algorithm.

Comment: @JimB correction on the format. Instead of 2ybc it should read as 0xBC, as in Hex. So, I need to figure out how to encode... which I am going to try as []byte(0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC).

Comment: @JimB alright, so I am getting closer. I figured out that I was suppose specify the key and iv as []byte{0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC}. Even though the [code](https://play.golang.org/p/g86TgoUf6P) runs, it is not encrypting or decrypting correctly.

Comment: You're using a random IV for encryption (which is good, though there's no reason for the literal values you're going to overwrite), you're not prepending the IV to the ciphertext, and you're trying to use `\xbc\xbc\xbc\xbc\xbc\xbc\xbc\xbc` for the decryption IV rather than anything prepended to the ciphertext.

Comment: @JimB I commented out the random IV in the following [code](https://play.golang.org/p/gIee9raIQV) and now the decryption is working. However, the encrypted string is not what I am expecting. I do not know how to prepend the IV to the ciphertext.

Comment: Just copy the iv to the ciphertext slice, and use that portion for decryption, which is the whole reason for prepending it: https://play.golang.org/p/9Qi7y8f-ha

Answer (score 0):

@JimB thank you for your clarifications! I ended up rewording the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41490851/golang-how-do-i-encrypt-plain-text-that-is-5-characters-long-with-des-and-cbc?noredirect=1#comment70188445_41490851) and found my answer.