# Golang: How do I encrypt plain text that is 5 characters long with DES and CBC?

Tags: go, base64, des, cbc-mode

Currently trying to encrypt plaintext that is 5 characters long into a 12 character encrypted string. I want to be able to specify a unique IV (not randomly generated), a unique key, and use DES. My current [code](https://play.golang.org/p/2JfiwG8gOF) requires the plaintext to be 8 characters long (5 character name plus 3 spaces).

Comment: You might be able to use PKCS7 padding: https://play.golang.org/p/SpEUHSMR9e

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/wBF8iYBbeV

Comment: @ralph suggests a good solution. DES works on 64 bit blocks, so padding is neccessary. PKCS7 is one solution. It adds n bytes with value n to the end of the plaintext where n is the amount of padding required. If your data is exactly the block size though, it requires an extra full block though to pad.

Comment: @ralph perhaps you should make an answer with that + a brief explanation.

Comment: here is some code I found that implements pad and unpad: https://github.com/go-web/tokenizer/blob/master/pkcs7.go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have already faced this problem. This is because of padding issue. The code you wanted is a

[Code link](https://play.golang.org/p/B9J123SCUz) You Can test it at go playground.

```
  package main

  import (
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/des"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
  )

  func main() {
    originalText := "yolan"
    fmt.Println(originalText)

    key := []byte{0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC}

    // encrypt value to base64
    cryptoText := encrypt(key, originalText)
    fmt.Println(cryptoText)

  }

  // encrypt string to base64 crypto using des
  func encrypt(key []byte, text string) string {
    plaintext := []byte(text)

    block, err := des.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    iv := []byte{0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC, 0xBC}

    blockSize := block.BlockSize()
    origData := PKCS5Padding(plaintext, blockSize)
    blockMode := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(block, iv)
    cryted := make([]byte, len(origData))
    blockMode.CryptBlocks(cryted, origData)

    return base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(cryted)
  }

  func PKCS5Padding(src []byte, blockSize int) []byte {
    padding := blockSize - len(src)%blockSize
    padtext := bytes.Repeat([]byte{byte(padding)}, padding)
    return append(src, padtext...)
  }

  func PKCS5UnPadding(src []byte) []byte {
    length := len(src)
    unpadding := int(src[length-1])
    return src[:(length - unpadding)]
  }
```